# Prevent in-app caching of values in localstorage on iOS

Tags: ios, html, cordova, caching, local-storage

We have an HTML5 app run through Phonegap to create native Android/iOS versions.  The app displays a chart to users based on their performance of answered questions within the app. The data displayed by the chart is called via json from the user's account on our server when the app first launches, and is then stored in localstorage, so the app can continue to be used if the user goes offline.

I'm calling the data for the chart as follows:

```
var totalQuestions = parseInt(jsonPath(performanceData, "$..AllQuestionCount"));
var Incorrect = parseInt(jsonPath(performanceData, "$..Incorrect"));
var Correct = parseInt(jsonPath(performanceData, "$..Correct"));
```

This works fine - at first. As the user answers questions, they are prompted to update their account with their results - this then updates their account via the web service. When they subsequently return to the 'page' displaying the chart, the chart should update with their recent results, e.g. the AllQuestionCount should be incremented by the number of questions they've just answered.

In the HTML5 and Android versions, this works as expected, which (to me) shows that localstorage is being updated with the new values correctly. But in iOS, the chart only updates when the app is closed and re-opened.

Interestingly, the chart in iOS didn't have this issue UNTIL we updated the Architectures to support arm64, and updated the Deployment Target from 5.0 to 6.0. This was done to meet Apple's new requirement for apps that they support 64bit.

My best guess is that because the `totalQuestions` var etc. have already been loaded, the app is now caching the values, rather than reloading the values from localstorage each time the chart loads.

Any thoughts on a solution to this?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: Use GapDebug and read out, when the Localstorage gets updatet and what values are inside of it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Not heard of GapDebug before. The fact that the HTML5 and Android versions work OK though - wouldn't that suggest an iOS issue, rather than a localstorage one?

Comment: Localstorage works perfectly fine as far as i know. I'm using it for several apps and never had problems with that. GapDebug is very great, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Sithys, I'm trying to get it debugging now. Do you have any idea why I can't see the app listed under my device? I've even installed it via GapDebug, and received a 'success' message, but it still doesn't display.